# android skipping a volley action

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem with my android app with Volley.

the app is skipping the volley action and all what I got is a null variable

is there any way to wait for the volley action to complete then go-ahead

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(urlpop, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


               appinter = jo.getString("inter");
                 appbanner = jo.getString("banner");
                 
                Log.d("EX DATA",appbanner);
                Log.d("EX DATA",appinter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You forgot to add request method `Request.Method.GET` in your request.

Use below code.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,urlpop, 
       new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                   appinter = jo.getString("inter");
                     appbanner = jo.getString("banner");

                    Log.d("EX DATA",appbanner);
                    Log.d("EX DATA",appinter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: hey thanks for you answer but even when added it still skipping